# Setting z-index when using jQuery UI Draggable not working in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have 2 draggable DIVs that that i want stacked depending on where in the parent DIV they are located. I tried to set  z-index, while this works in IE 9, I cannot get it to work in Firefox 4.

Using Firebug I see that the dragged elements has z-index set to auto.

Full demo of what I want to accomplish at http://jsfiddle.net/a5jgm/6/

Thank you for your time

```
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
    //    zIndex: 5,
        start: function(event, ui) {
        //    console.log(this);
            var zIndex = $(this).draggable( "option", "zIndex" );
            $('#zindex').val(zIndex);
        //    $( this ).draggable( "option", "zIndex", 100 );
        },            
        drag: function( event, ui ) {                
            var pos = $( "#"+this.id).position();
            $( "#offset" ).val( ""+pos.left +" "+pos.top );
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            console.log(this);
            if(ui.offset.left > 220){
                var currentz = parseInt( $('#zindex').val() )+1;

                $( this ).draggable( "option", "zIndex", currentz);    
                $('#zindex').val(currentz);
                console.log(' z index is: '+$(this).draggable( "option", "zIndex" ));
            }

        }
    });
    var i = 10;
    $( ".draggable").each(function(){
        i = i +1;
        $( this ).draggable( "option", "zIndex", i );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the position attribute as well. Set it to relative, absolute etc whichever is appropriate as per your implementation. That might probably solve the issue.

Comment: The .draggable class already has absolute, setting to relative does not help